# How to get build environment and configuration parameters of the Qt library

Tags: qt, build, configuration

There is a issue that is present with some very specific aspect of applications I build using a Qt library provided in repositories of the system I'm using; this issue isn't present with the same numerical build of Qt that I built myself on this exact system.

I would like to query all information about build environment of Qt, it's configuration flags, etc., anything that could help me determine the difference between two build of Qt library.

I've learned about `config.summary` file, that is present in mine `qtbase` sources, but there isn't a counterpart anywhere in the system for pre-built version (I have, besides headers, installed a sources and debug information for the qt library packages).

I also tried looking for some header files that could specify, for example, what features were enabled at the build time, but could't locate anything like that (mostly because I don't know the name or some example contents of such file so that I could search for it or grep it), so if there is indeed such file, please point me to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best reply is to quote [this answer](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2018-May/032762.html) from Qt mailing list

> Unfortunately it isn't that easy to figure out but the data is
>   available; you just need to know from where to search it :D
>
> Configure options can be found from (qtbase) build log, from qt5.git
>   integration. E.g for 5.6.3
>   here:https://testresults.qt.io/coin/integration/qt/qt5/tasks/1505476672
>   and for 5.9.5 here:
>   https://testresults.qt.io/coin/integration/qt/qt5/tasks/1523412986
>
> And SW details here: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.6_Tools_and_Versions &
>   https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.9_Tools_and_Versions

You can find the latest builds at https://testresults.qt.io/coin/?project=qt%2Fqt5

If you look inside the "Build" section you have all the system configurations Qt is built for (column "Target") and for each configuration the parameters (column "Configure Arguments").

Comment: Unfortunately my Qt build isn't made publicly; it's a local build in a company build system (which I currently don't have access to so I can't just look at spec file or something). And if I understand correctly, a lot depends on the environment Qt was built in, that is, which libraries are installed at the build time and etc. That's what I'm (probably) most curious about.